# tensorflow persistance of TextVectorisaition

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have just upgraded tensorflow to the latest version and see that model looses preprocessing layer info during serialisation:

Old working code :

```
def mk_model(vocab_size = 2000 , embeding_dim = 64 , lstm_dim = 64):
    tokenizer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(max_tokens=vocab_size,)
    tokenizer.adapt(train_dataset.map(lambda text,cat, label: text))

    print("Vocab size" ,tokenizer.vocabulary_size())
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string,name="text_input"),
        tokenizer,
        tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
            input_dim=len(tokenizer.get_vocabulary()),
            output_dim=embeding_dim,
            # Use masking to handle the variable sequence lengths
            mask_zero=True),
        tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(lstm_dim)), # 64
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(lstm_dim, activation='relu'), # 64
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(label_encoder.classes_))
    ])

    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    return model,tokenizer
```

saved model using model.save command in format with input

```
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  inputs['text_vectorization_91_input'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_STRING
      shape: (-1)
      name: serving_default_text_vectorization_91_input:0
```

on the latest versions of tensorflow/keras i need to do

```
tf.saved_model.save(
    model,
    export_dir=model_sig_export_path,
)
```

to produce the same format which can be served by `tsserve` but it produces the model without preprocessing layer:

```
  inputs['inputs'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (-1, 1)
      name: serving_default_inputs:0
```

What is the common way to implement the same functionality with persistence ?